# How to split Rails edit form into two actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an edit form that has way too many fields. I would like to split it into two different actions (`:edit` and `:advanced_options`).

The standard edit action submits to the update action and if there are form errors, it renders the edit action:

```
if @model.update_attributes(params[:model])
  redirect_to model_path(@model), notice: 'Model was successfully updated.'
else
  render action: "edit"
end
```

How can I make it so the update action is smart enough to render the advanced_options form in case of form errors?

Comment: You might want to consider using using Wicked for this, see: https://github.com/schneems/wicked.  Sounds like a mulit-part form wizard to me.

Comment: and a cast http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked

Comment: Wicked looks like a pretty cool gem for wizard-style forms. However, my situation isn't really a wizard and was hoping for a simple solution.